# iText 5 creating a page with 2 writing orientations

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I am trying to create a PDF with iText5 in java. For a report i'm trying to generate i need to rotate the page of the PDF 180 deg before continuing to write the report. I'm currently trying to rotate it with a pageEvent during the writing.

```
public class RotateEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {
  public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
      writer.addPageDictEntry(PdfName.ROTATE, PdfPage.INVERTEDPORTRAIT);
  }
}

public static void makeKlantSpecificPDF(List<Klant> klanten, String path) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(".." + File.separator  + path));
    document.open();

    document.add(new Paragraph("test"));
    writer.setPageEvent(new RotateEvent());
    document.add(new Paragraph("test"));
    document.close();
}
```

but instead of rotating the page nothing happens and the 2 test paragraphs are written below each other. To further complicate the matter this has to work in a for loop per two items in the "klanten" list.

Is there any possible solution for changing the write rotation while writing the page.

Comment: full github repo @ https://github.com/Gschrooyen/Restaurantdag

Comment: Hi Glenn, I noticed that your GitHub repo is missing a `LICENSE` file. You need AGPLv3 if you use iText. See https://github.com/Gschrooyen/Restaurantdag/community for other suggestions. Also, if you're starting out with iText, then I recommend that you use iText 7. Also, I see a `.idea` folder in your repo. This is often excluded with a `.gitignore` file. And have you considered using a build tool like Maven or Gradle? Then you don't have to store huuuuge binaries in a lib folder.

Comment: `writer.addPageDictEntry(PdfName.ROTATE, PdfPage.INVERTEDPORTRAIT);` sets the page rotation value. This value counts for everything on the page, no matter if drawn before or after.